# How to post back the data from an okhttp async thread to the ArrayAdapter in main thread?

Tags: android, listview, okhttp

My intention is to get back data fetched from a server via an okhttp interface. The okhttp method is run in async and therefore on a separate thread from the activity. The activity in question is a fragment that creates a listView. Im trying to populate that listView with the data from okhttp by means of an ArrayAdapter.

How to post back the data from the okhttp async thread to the ArrayAdapter?

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);
    final ListView listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.friendListView);

    ArrayAdapter<String> listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nfl);
    listview.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);


    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    String url = "http://192.168.8.101:7777/friendlist";
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
            }
            String RD = response.body().string();
            String trimmedList = RD.substring(1, RD.length()-1);
            String[] fl = trimmedList.split(",");
            final List<String> nfl = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String element : fl){
                String ee = element.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
                nfl.add(ee);
            }


        }
    });


    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference to the activity's instance you could create a runnable that populates the adapter and run it using the activity's `runOnUiThread` method

checkout the documentation :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

Comment: How can I get an instance of the activity from within the worker thread then?

Comment: If I understood you code right then you have created the worker thread inside a Fragment if that was the case you could use  the method  getAcitvity(), other wise you could pass an instance of your activity to the thread but make sure it's a week reference to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you, that is the answer! (Ill update it below)

Answer (score 0):

You must initiate your adapter and list inside onResponse CallBack. If there's no response, just show an error dialog, otherwise, initiate your adapter with the result. The code must look like:

```
@Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
            }
            String RD = response.body().string();
            String trimmedList = RD.substring(1, RD.length()-1);
            String[] fl = trimmedList.split(",");
            final List<String> nfl = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String element : fl){
                String ee = element.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
                nfl.add(ee);
            }
//Put your code for showing the list item here.
ArrayAdapter<String> listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nfl);
    listview.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);


        }
```

Comment: That cannot be right. When I do such I get a `FATAL EXCEPTION: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

Comment: Make aninterface with the method onResponse(List<String> resultList) and when you get your data call this method and put as argument your result list, and make your activity implement this method and take the list from argument and show it !

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to create a `runOnUiThread` and invoke the ArrayAdapter within a `runnable()`

Here is the correct code:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);
    final ListView listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.friendListView);


    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    String url = "http://192.168.8.101:7777/friendlist/" + USERNAME;
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
            }
            String RD = response.body().string();
            response.close();
            String trimmedList = RD.substring(1, RD.length()-1);
            String[] fl = trimmedList.split(",");
            final List<String> nfl = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String element : fl){
                String ee = element.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
                nfl.add(ee);
            }

            System.out.println(nfl);
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ArrayAdapter<String> listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nfl);
                    listview.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
                }
            });

        }
    });


    return view;
}
```